# java.lang.SecurityException: Provider gps requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I try to develope an Android map application, utilizing the Google maps API.

Testing on several emulatet Android devices (2.1; 2.3.3;4.0.3) all with Google API.

The problem is that logcat throws this at me:

```
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{map.test.activity/map.test.activity.MapTestActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Provider gps requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Provider gps requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:646)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:582)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:446)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at map.test.activity.MapTestActivity.onCreate(MapTestActivity.java:29)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-05 04:39:57.519: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  ... 11 more
```

Here is the code:

```
package map.test.activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class MapTestActivity extends MapActivity {

    private MapController mapController;
    private MapView mapView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); // bind the layout to the activity

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(10); // Zoom 1 is world view
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                        0, new GeoUpdateHandler());
    } //public void 

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }// protected boolean

    public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
                    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
                    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
                    mapController.animateTo(point);
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
    }

} //public class MapTestActivity
```

And the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="map.test.activity" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCES_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCES_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" /> 

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MapTestActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I already tried shifting the position of the permissions and setting the compiler to JAVA 1.6 (and adding @Override to the last three public voids).
It's propably something really obvious but I just started developing in Java.

Answer (score 7):

You misspelled

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCES_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCES_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

It should be

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: The fine location permission should fix this. Are you sure it is still generating the same exception?

Answer (score 7):

Make sure the uses-permission element is not in the application element. I accidentally pasted it in there once, and Android Studio doesn't tell you that's a problem. Once I moved it out, it fixed the issue.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.someapp.app" >

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

  <application ...>

...
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same error message as you did, but in my case it turned out to be because I had used just

```
permission
```

instead of

```
uses-permission
```

Hopefully this will save someone an afternoon of debugging ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Very Silly mistake you have done. You must not remove `"@Override`" from the above line of `OnCreate()` Method. Add that line and try running your code again.

Comment: @Override is just an annotation, it is recommended to use it to specify overriding, but has no direct effect in operation of the related code...